# Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis

В общем, вызываю в Main:

```
var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe));
```

А далее метод:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, bool isService)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IsService", isService.ToString()) })
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddSerilog(new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                .CreateLogger());
        })
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIIS()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

И когда пытаюсь все это запустить в IIS, то ловлю ошибку:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The
> configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not
> optional. The physical path is
> 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appsettings.json'.

Почему он ищет конфигурационный файл не в той папке? Я же указал путь к базовой директории...

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, так как я хостю это дело все внутри процесса IIS, то

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

Показывает путь к IIS'у.

Я сменил метод определения базовой директории на:

```
new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath
```

И все заработало.

Правда, не понимаю 1 момента:

Почему при дебаге там отображается путь к исполняемому файлу, а когда из под IIS запускаешь, то туда попадает путь к директории...

Буду признателен за пояснение в комментариях.

Comment: Не понял, что вам непонятно, сами пишите же `все внутри процесса IIS`

Comment: Когда вы таким образом разворачиваете приложение, то жизненным циклом вашего приложения управляет IIS, в том числе и запускает его! По этому текущий процесс, является процессом IIS. Посмотрите в дебаге объект Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule, вам сразу все станет понятнее. А в дебаге вы сами запускаете свое приложение, оно селф хостид, и запускается из того места где расположена EntryPoint. Кстати, корректный путь можно получить и так `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: @4per это да. Но не понятно, почему если из под дебага, когда я запускаю, то путь к экзехе отображается, а когда IIS хостит, то там путь к директории с исполняемым файлом, хотя ожидаю тоже исполняемый файл...

Comment: Так вы получает Process.GetCurrentProcess() текущий процесс, а это с исполняемым файлом не связано. А вот второе решение как раз связано - вы получаете исполняемую сборку и путь ее расположения.

Comment: @kurtov под "вторым решением" вы понимаете new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath ? Вот он как раз если из под IIS смотреть, то путь к директории возвращает.